# One column or two column resume for passing the ATS?

Tags: resume, applications

I will be applying for graduate student internships for summer 2015, and I am interested in making a good quality resume. I am planning to use latex to typeset it.

Most companies, such as JP Morgan, seem to require 1 page resumes. Which means I need to pack in as much information as possible.

Hence I had the following questions:

1. Is it advisable then to use CV with 2 columns (like [this](http://www.latextemplates.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/cv_3.png)) or a standard CV without columns (such as [this](http://www.latextemplates.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/cv_11.png)) ? The 2 columns format seems to be able to stuff in more information.
2. Often softwares will parse through the initial set of resumes a company receives. Does the layout, (1 column or 2 column) affect the ability of the 
   software to parse through the resume?
3. This might be a stupid question, but do such softwares parsing pdfs 
   do better on pdfs generated with latex rather than a pdf generated by exporting a resume written in a microsoft word doc format.

Comment: 2 columns actually ought to give you _less_ efficient use of the page, since you lose the "gutter" between the two columns which could otherwise carry text. Unless you have a lot of very short lines or blank lines, I'd be surprised if it helped you that way... but you can try it both ways and see. Personally, I still think the simplest solution (ordinary plaintext) wins unless you're applying for a job where your ability to make a page pretty matters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, if you're a grad student applying for internships, you really shouldn't need more than a page for your resume.  If you think you do, get someone who's not a student to go through it and cut out the irrelevant bits.

1. No. Two-column CVs are weird.
2. Since PDF is a presentational format, not a structured one, the parser may have difficulty with two columns and try to mash them together.  So a single column is better.
3. I would suspect that LaTeX PDFs will be slightly cleaner, but as noted above, turning PDFs back into text is a very inexact science and the result will never be perfect.  Consider a parsable document format (RTF or Word) if you really think this is important.

Comment: With over 30 years of experience I have a two page resume, I can't imagine what the OP would want to put in a resume that would be over a page at that level. Most interviewers would never read a second page or more for an entry level person.